# Facet pretty path providing no result

Tags: commerce, search

I have used commerce kickstart and created product display page with facet filter.I have used **[Facet API Pretty Paths module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_pretty_paths)** to use simple URL.But it makes no result behaviour.Without facet pretty path, facet filter working good, but URL makes quite complex.

Comment: Can you give the version of facet api pretty path you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is a bug in Facet API Pretty Paths module. 
take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2423029 and ask maintainer to solve or suggest a solution for it.